# Take first sign pine script

Tags: pine-script, trading

I've been trying for the build sign in version 2. However this is getting executed in version 4.
Can someone help me with this in version 2? Thank you so much

[image]

```
// Determine currently LONG or SHORT
isLong = nz(isLong[1], false)
isShort = nz(isShort[1], false)

// Buy or Sell only if the buy signal is triggered and not already long or short
buySignal = not isLong and buy
sellSignal = not isShort and sell

if (buySignal)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellSignal)
    isLong := false
    isShort := true
    
plotshape(series=buySignal, text='Buy', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, offset=0, color=#009688, textcolor=#ffffff, size=size.small)

plotshape(series=sellSignal, text='Sell', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, offset=0, color=#F44336, textcolor=#ffffff, size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your script to `v5` and get rid of `isShort`, you don't need it.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

_sma = ta.sma(close, 9)

buy = ta.crossover(close, _sma)
sell = ta.crossunder(close, _sma)

// Determine currently LONG or SHORT
var isLong = false

// Buy or Sell only if the buy signal is triggered and not already long or short
buySignal = not isLong and buy
sellSignal = isLong and sell

if (buySignal)
    isLong := true

if (sellSignal)
    isLong := false

plot(_sma)
plotshape(series=buySignal, text='Buy', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, offset=0, color=#009688, textcolor=#ffffff, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=sellSignal, text='Sell', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, offset=0, color=#F44336, textcolor=#ffffff, size=size.small)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much .. I really appreciate it ..